# Java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I try to create unity Subview for my android app. But I got a error like this

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1750): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.duy/com.duy.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout
```

This is my Java code

```
package com.duy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private UnityPlayer m_UnityPlayer;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create the UnityPlayer
        m_UnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        int glesMode = m_UnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        m_UnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Add the Unity view
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);    
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        layout.addView(m_UnityPlayer.getView(), 0, lp);
    }
}
```

and this is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I got the following error:

```
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Process: com.duy, PID: 1913
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Unity version     : 5.1.1f1
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Device model      : unknown Android SDK built for x86
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Device fingerprint: generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/999428:eng/test-keys
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.duy/com.duy.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.duy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-24 09:20:41.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     ... 11 more
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.frameLayout2` is NOT a frame layout. Look at your XML again.

That means the line: `FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);` is wrong, so you have a `ClassCastException`

But if all you want is to have the unity player view, you can use just that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the UnityPlayer
    m_UnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
    int glesMode = m_UnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    m_UnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

    setContentView(m_UnityPlayer.getView());
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly for me? I try to follow this tutorial http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-unity-android-in-a-sub-view.98315/  but it don't work . Help me, please. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more clear. I gave the complete working solution for you. `ClassCastException` is basic Java. A class is of one type you tried to cast it to a different type. `findViewById` returns you a type of `View`, in your XML layout this is a `RelativeLayout`, but then on your code you tried to cast it to `(FrameLayout)` they're not the same, so it crashes. But all of this is irrelevant if u want the content to be the unity content, you just call to put the unity view in the content, no FrameLayout, no RelativeLayout

Comment: I've edited the relativelayout to FrameLayout but I still get the error 06-24 10:22:41.279: E/ActivityThread(2141): Activity com.duy.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$3@b1f51ee0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Comment: that's a different issue, ask a different question to someone else

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem:**
Basically you have tried to cast a Framelayout to a Relativelayout, in your xml you can see it is a relativelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout><!--Notice it says Relativelayout-->
```

You can't do this:

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
```

Because it is actually a Relativelayout, not a Framelayout, even though you called it 'framelayout2' it is still a Relativelayout.

**Solution 1:**
I recommend this one as you end up with a framelayout and that follows your tutorial more accurately. Change the Relativelayout in the XML file into a framelayout, it's very simple:

New XML File:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</FrameLayout><!--Notice it says FrameLayout Now.-->
```

This will completely solve your problem, with no extra steps.

**Solution 2:**
You could also change the code in you Java to reflect that it is a relativelayout, however this doesn't follow your tutorial as much but it's good to know.

New Java:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout2);
```

That should also work, but again that makes it a relativelayout no a framelayout so it might mess up your tutorial.